# replacing objects in list/string using dynamically created substring variables (or loops) using python

Tags: python, nested-loops

I'm new to coding and had a question about how to replace objects in a list and end with a list of strings that contain all possible combinations for these letter substitutions.

I am working with biological data (like a dna sequence for example). Say we have something that looks like this:

primer = "CATTTTCHACTAAYCATAARGATATTGG"

At each degenerate letter (not an A, C, T, or G), I need to replace it with another letter (A, C, G, or T).

-H can be replaced with A, C or T 
-Y can be replaced with C or T 
-R can be replaced with A or G

Ideally, I would like my script to go through the primer sequence and upon the first degenerate letter (H), create three new sequences by replacing H with A, C, and T:

Original: CATTTTC**H**

```
        Seq 1: CATTTTC**A**
        Seq 2: CATTTTC**C**
        Seq 3: CATTTTC**T**
```

and continue through. Then at the next degenerate letter (Y), branch off and make more sequences:

```
    Original Seq 1: CATTTTC**A**CTAA**Y**

           Seq 1.1: CATTTTC**A**CTAA**C**
           Seq 1.2: CATTTTC**A**CTAA**T**

    Original Seq 2: CATTTTC**C**CTAA**Y**

           Seq 2.1: CATTTTC**C**CTAA**C**
           Seq 2.2: CATTTTC**C**CTAA**T**

    Original Seq 3: CATTTTC**T**CTAA**Y**

           Seq 3.1: CATTTTC**T**CTAA**C**
           Seq 3.2: CATTTTC**T**CTAA**T**

                           Etc.....
```

At the end, I would like to have a list of strings with all possible combinations. How would I go about doing this?

## Attempt 1:

```
holdletter = ""  #this is a fake/empty variable
primer = "CATTTTCHACTAAYCATAARGATATTGG"
primerconverted = ""
listOfPrimerConverts = \[\]
listOfPrimerChar = list(primer)

for letter in primer:
  if letter == "H":
  holdletter = letter.replace("H", "A")
  primerconverted + holdletter
  print(primerconverted)

   else continue

\#not sure whats happening below but this is my scratch paper
\#help

for char in listOfPrimerChar:
  if char is "C" or "T" or "A" or "G":
    listOfPrimerConverts.append(char)
      continue

  if char is "H":
    listOfPrimerConverts.append(primerconverted + "A")
    listOfPrimerConverts.append(primerconverted + "C")
    listOfPrimerConverts.append(primerconverted + "T")
```

## Attempt 2:

```
\#Degenerate Primer Key

H = A, C, or T
V = A, C, or G
N = A, C, T, G
Y = pyrimidines (C or T)
R = A or G
D = A, G, or T)

\#---------------------------------

Primer Identification: COI bcdF01

primer = "CATTTTCHACTAAYCATAARGATATTGG"

print()

print("Primer list: ", list(primer)) #copy output into primer_list

primer_character_list = list(primer)

\#for i in primer:
  print(i)

print()

print("Primer length: ", len(primer));

print()

\#primer_character_list = \['C', 'A', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'C', 'H', 'A', 'C', 'T', 'A', 'A', 'Y', 'C', 'A', 'T', 'A', 'A', 'R', 'G', 'A', 'T', 'A', 'T', 'T', 'G', 'G'\]

\#primer_character_list\[0\] == position # how do i assign a position to all characters in this list???

print()

cnt = 1
for i in primer:
    for j in i:
       print('position', cnt, end=': ')
       print(j)
       cnt = cnt + 1      

print()

print("Degenerate Primer Characters & Positions")

print()

primer = "CATTTTCHACTAAYCATAARGATATTGG"
letter = 'H'
print("Letter H is at position: ", primer.rfind(letter) +1)

print()

primer = "CATTTTCHACTAAYCATAARGATATTGG"
letter = 'Y'
print("Letter Y is at position: ", primer.rfind(letter) +1)

print()

primer = "CATTTTCHACTAAYCATAARGATATTGG"
letter = 'R'
print("Letter R is at position: ", primer.rfind(letter) +1)

print()

holdletter = ""
primerconverted = primer + holdletter
for letter in primer:
  if letter == "H":
    primer[7] = position7
    #holdletter = letter.replace("H", "A")

    print(primerconverted)
```

Comment: you should try the `re` module.  `import re`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this

```py
from itertools import product as p

primer = 'CATTTTCHACTAAYCATAARGATATTGG'

rep = {'H': ['A', 'C', 'T'],
'Y': ['C',  'T'],
'R': ['A', 'G']
}

combinations = list(rep.get(i, i) for i in primer)

a = list(p(*combinations))
for comb in a:
    print(''.join(comb))
```